# select max sum of user from table, as user with maximum amount?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a table as

```
create table mock_sales
(
    first_name character varying,
    last_name character varying,
    amount integer
);

insert into mock_sales(first_name, last_name, amount) 
values('ted','mosby', 100),
('lily', 'aldrin', 400),
('ted', 'mosby', 350),
('barney', 'Stinson',180)
```

**Output Desired**

Person with max sum amount

***ted mosby*** // As ted mosby sum  = 450 (100 + 350), which is largest

**I tried**

```
Select first_name, last_name from mock_sales group by first_name, last_name where amount in (
select max(amount) from t
(select sum(amount) as amount from mock_sales as t group by first_name, last_name)

or 

select t.first_name, t.last_name from mock_sales where max(amount) == t.amount and t.amount in (
Select first-name, last_name, sum(amount) as amount from mock_sales as t group by first_name, last_name)
```

But they both gave syntax errors. Any help will be appreciated.

Having trouble joining the result of 2 queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the sum instead of max value so, try this instead:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM mock_sales 
 GROUP BY first_name,last_name ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I don't want that as output, I want ted mosby as output as (sum of ted mosby 100 + 350 = 450, is larger than lily aldrin 400.

Answer (score 1):

You can just group records having the same first/last name, order the results and keep the first row only:

```
select first_name, last_name, sum(amount) total_amount
from mock_sales
group by first_name, last_name
order by total_amount desc
limit 1
```

If you want to allow ties, then it is a bit different. In Postgres, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select first_name, last_name, sum(amount) total_amount,
        rank() over(order by sum(amount) desc) rn
    from mock_sales
    group by first_name, last_name
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes this will work, I am taking about solution with limit 1, but can we somehow write this query without using limit.  Or how will it compare if we somehow use max function in terms of time complexity

Comment: @John: if you want just one row and don't care about ties, `order by` and `limit` should be the most efficient option. You can test against your real data and see by yourself. For performance, consider an index on `(first_name, last_name, amount)`.